# when to stop training object detection tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am training faster rcnn model on fruit dataset using a pretrained model provided in google api(faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco).

I made few changes to the default configuration. (number of classes : 12 fine_tune_checkpoint: path to the pretrained checkpoint model and from_detection_checkpoint: true). Total number of annotated images I have is around 12000.

After training for 9000 steps, the results I got have an accuracy percent below 1, though I was expecting it to be atleast 50% (In evaluation nothing is getting detected as accuracy is almost 0). The loss fluctuates in between 0 and 4.[image]

What should be the number of steps I should train it for. I read an article which says to run around 800k steps but its the number of step when you train from scratch?

FC layers of the model are changed because of the different number of the classes but it should not effect those classes which are already present in the pre-trained model like 'apple'?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Something is wrong, time will not help can you post a git diff of your changes?

Comment: The model wasnt training it from the checkpoint,rather it started from the scratch. I got error : " WARNING:root:Variable [FirstStageFeatureExtractor/InceptionResnetV2/Conv2d_1a_3x3/BatchNorm/beta] not available in checkpoint" when I tried it from checkpoint. I think I will just see how my model trains itself if not then I will have to look for some pre-trained model which is compatible with my model. Thanks !!

Comment: try using an earlier version of tensorflow, or rename the variables in the checkpoint to the new automatic names.

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't look at your training loss to determine when to stop. Instead, you should run your model through the evaluator periodically, and stop training when the evaluation mAP stops improving.

Comment: Training loss is proportional to the mAP, right ? If the loss is less then it indicates that the model is well trained or may be over trained, but then again it will give me accuracy of atleast more than 50 %.

Comment: Well first it'd be inversely proportional, but I believe that's not always the case anyway. Training loss could potentially go up at the same time evaluation mAP goes up.

Comment: I somehow got the impression that when the total loss is below 2.0, it is time to stop.

Comment: That intuition would be totally wrong, as for me the total loss is usually below 2.0 right from the very beginning.